# Checking companion app returned: No such native application net.downloadhelper.coapp, that is a response and in sense companion app is installed

Tags: firefox-extensions

Checking companion app returned: No such native application net.downloadhelper.coapp, that is a response and in sense companion app is installed in my computer with Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Comment: Please EDIT the question and add more details. As asked there is nothing to suggest as an answer.

Comment: Which companion app are you talking about? I second David's request for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the end for the only solution I have found:

I have this same issue. I stumbled upon this post doing a search for the error message.

The poster is asking about how to get the Video Download Helper for Firefox or Chrome browser extension working in Ubuntu 22.04.

This extension worked in 20.04 and I believe earlier versions as I have been using both for many years. I had issues with the 22.04 upgrade and so had to erase and do a clean install.

Attempting to download a video from the extension prompts the user to install the companion app. There are 3 methods: 1. A .deb 2. Command line for single user 3. Command line for all users

No matter which method is used to install the companion app, the browser extension replies: Companion app not installed: Checking companion app returned: Specified native messaging host not found.

I could be wrong, but I suspect in 22.04 browsers or extensions are sandboxed into a directory and don't have access to where the companion app is being installed.

I tried uninstalling firefox and installing from command line, but that only reinstalled the snap. So I uninstalled again, verified it was uninstalled, and installed firefox from flathub. Then reinstalled the companion app using all 3 methods, restarting the browser and checking for the companion app each time, and it never found it.

So I tried using the Chrome extension, but it could not find the companion app in Chrome either.

The issue has been reported at the project Github at: https://github.com/mi-g/vdhcoapp/issues/137

**********SOLUTION**********
Install Firefox via “Mozilla Team” team PPA

See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/

After reinstalling Firefox, you have to reinstall the Video Download Helper extension and the Companion App

UPDATE: As of October 2022, this method no longer works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).